# Is there a way to turn a TFS instance into read-only mode?

Tags: tfs

We are migrating a TFS instance from 2008 to 2010.

To minimize the risk, we are installing TFS 2010 on new hardware and we plan to leave the old TFS 2008 instance on for a while until we are sure everything is working OK on the new server.

To avoid people updating the 2008 instance instead of the 2010 one by mistake, I was planning to turn it into read-only mode. That should include:

- Version Control
- Project Portal Documents
- Work Items

The way I'm envisioning on doing this is to change the security permission groups (almost) all to read-only.

Is there a simpler (as in a single switch) or more proper of doing this?

Comment: You might have a better chance of getting an answer if this is on StackOverflow.  I can move it there if you'd like.

Comment: I wasn't sure where I should have posted this question and decided to post it here since its more related to configuring the server than to software development per se. Anyway, I'll be more than grateful if you could move it there.

Comment: I'll kick it over there then. I think that devs would be able to get you a better answer.

Comment: What is not simple about removing all rights but read?

Comment: If there were a single switch to do it, it would be simpler to toggle that switch than to fiddle with several custom security groups

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you put the database in read-only mode, this will break things in TFS.  For example, every command adds an entry to tbl_command table, so no one will be able to look at the Team Project.

The best option might be to change the permissions on the Team Project so no one has write access.

Comment: Your answer somewhat details the comment I've made to @TrueWill 's answer. Also note that I have specified TFS version to be 2008. There's no such thing as (Team Project) collections in TFS 2008.

Answer (score 0):

I think TFS uses SQL Server as a back-end. You could put the database into read-only mode.

EDIT: I checked with the person who administered our migration. He said that our DBAs:

> ... put the database in read-only mode. That prevented people from
>   changing things during migration but it also had the side-effect of
>   preventing an actual connection to the TFS database so people couldn’t
>   even get copies or read items in TFS as a result. There is probably a
>   better way, but it did accomplish the goal of preventing changes
>   during the migration.

So Alfred Myers and @Erin Geaney are correct. Hopefully there is a better way.

Comment: Yes, it does use SQL Server as a back-end. But putting SQL Server into read-only mode will probably break something. Some of the tables in there are used for logging access through TFS Web Services. I'm not sure I want to go down the path of hunting which tables are those.